# Invalid import path - Go + windows

Tags: windows, go, import

When attempting to import to files from the windows file system:

```
import (
    pb "github.com\\sewelol\\sgx-decryption-service\\decryptionservice"
    dev "github.com\\sewelol\\sgx-decryption-service\\device"
    "google.golang.org\\rpc"`
)
```

I get this error

`server\main.go:10:5: invalid import path: "github.com\\sewelol\\sgx-decryption-service\\decryptionservice"`

I have checked `$PATH` enviroment variable includes the directory that has `github.com`, and `$GOROOT` also is set up to point to the Go installation.

I assume it is something to do with the file paths themselves, but I can't find any information on how to do filepaths in the windows environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use forward slashes `/` in import paths (of import declarations), even if you're on Windows.

[Spec: Import declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations)

> Implementation restriction: A compiler may restrict ImportPaths to non-empty strings using only characters belonging to [Unicode's](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.3.0/) L, M, N, P, and S general categories (the Graphic characters without spaces) and **may also exclude the characters `!"#$%&'()*,:;<=>?[\]^`{|}` and the Unicode replacement character U+FFFD**.

Any compiler may exclude the backslash `\` character among others. Even if you would use one that doesn't, your code would not be portable.

So instead try:

```
import (
    pb "github.com/sewelol/sgx-decryption-service/decryptionservice"
    dev "github.com/sewelol/sgx-decryption-service/device"
    "google.golang.org/rpc"
)
```